# In r/formattable, how to make `total` row in bold and size=8

Tags: r, formattable

In r/formattable, how to make `total` row in bold and size=8 ?

```
library(formattable)
df <- data.frame(category=c('a','b','total'),value=c(1,2,3))
formattable(df,list(
  category = formatter("span",
                       style = x ~ style(color = "red")
                       )
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following `formatter` like this:

```r
library(formattable)
lg_bold_color_size <- formatter("span", style = ~style("font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "8", 'color' = 'red'))
df <- data.frame(category=c('a','b','total'),value=c(1,2,3))
formattable(df, list(area(row = 3) ~ lg_bold_color_size))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it' can't work when combine with my previous code . Could help on this ? Thanks! 
 library(formattable)
df <- data.frame(category=c('a','b','total'),value=c(1,2,3))
formattable(df,
            list(
  category = formatter("span",style = x ~ style(color = "red"))),
  list(area(row = 3) ~ formatter("span",
                                 style = y ~ style(font.weight = 'bold',font.size=18,color='red'))
))

Comment: Hi @anderwyang, Could you please explain what you want? The output gives bold size 8 right? I am not completely sure what you mean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911980/in-r-formattable-the-total-cell-finally-show-span-style-front-weight-boldt    . Thanks, you can refer to this post, I show the problem